# Node AWS Lambda POST to Twitter with User context Auth

Tags: node.js, twitter, aws-lambda, twitter-oauth

I am attempting to create a Node lambda on AWS which will authenticate with the Twitter API, via the `twit` npm module, in User Context. So that the lambda can then upload a GIF and then once uploaded, tweet on the user's timeline using the returned media_id.

I have created a twitter app etc. It works, however it is posting the tweet to the account associated with the app, instead of the user's timeline. Here is my entire lambda code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '...',
    consumer_secret:      '...',
    access_token:         '...',
    access_token_secret:  '...'
});


module.exports.oauth = (event, context, callback) => {

        var b64content = fs.readFileSync('./testGIF.gif', { encoding: 'base64' })

        // POST the media to Twitter
        T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
          // assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers etc
          var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string
          var altText = "Alt text"
          var meta_params = { media_id: mediaIdStr, alt_text: { text: altText } }

          T.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function (err, data, response) {
            if (!err) {
              // reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
              var params = { status: 'Testing, GIF Sharing', media_ids: [mediaIdStr] }

              T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
                console.log(data)
              })
            }
          })
        })

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
  };

  callback(null, response);

};
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using tokens for the user account associated with the app.

You'll need to obtain an OAuth token on the user's behalf and use that to make authorized calls to Twitter's APIs.

You need to first create a webpage for your twitter app, then do any of the following:

- implement a twitter signin to directly capture an OAUTH token
- implement a three legged authorization to directly capture an OAUTH token
- use a [PIN-based authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based)

Once you have captured OAUTH token for the user, you can passed it on to your lambda to be used to initialize the `Twit` client.

https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The Twit docs mentioned that the token object I created was for user context but I guess not. Have you used any npm modules to achieve options A or B mentioned above?

Comment: Actually, the token object you created was for your personal user context. I think this is possible using twit. Making a gist for an example. I'll link to it as soon as I'm done.

Comment: Looking at this more and more, it seems I need to do three legged auth, in order to post on someone else's behalf? But I can't seem to find an example of this in Node

Comment: I wrote an example of 3 legged auth using expressjs as a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/osule/5ea0a673c0ed05c2ceaf178f0d12aaba). You can decide to do this process before making a request to your lambda or do it in your lambda. If you choose the later, you'll need to setup persistence for the token between requests.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna give that a shot now and see if it works :)

Comment: does the app/webhook need to be whitelisted by Twitter before I can test this properly or will it just work when I create a new twitter app? A POST request didn't seem to trigger my endpoint when I clicked `Sign in with Twitter`

Comment: It's a GET request that's made to your endpoint. It should work with the URL passed when you initialized the oauth client.

Comment: Ah, yes it is indeed, whoops :) Thank you so much, that worked really well!